# Is there any alternatives to 'codewars.com' or 'hackerrank.com' which also checks the time and space complexity of the written program?

Tags: computer-science

I am looking for a coding training platform like mentioned in the question, also with the feature which checks the program for time and space complexity.

I am asking something like mentioned in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKO9UjSeLew) video.

Thank you.

Comment: That seems impossible.  You could measure the time and space used for particular inputs and try to guess, but determining the true asymptotic complexity would run into the halting problem.

Comment: Let say the input is limited, say 0 < n < 10k. Wouldn't it be then possible to find the algorithm's complexities?

Comment: If the input is limited then the notion of asymptotic complexity has no meaning.  For instance, if n < 10000 then the function f(n)=n^2 is O(n), since f(n) <= 10000n for all n.

Comment: Ok, I get that. BUT, the follow-up question is, as you said in the beginning, can the system randomly select values for n in the range, and estimate the time it takes to run the program or whether the program needs time more than a specific time ( say time < c*n^2, where c is based on the system's throughput )? and if the time is greater than the expected time, show the error.

Comment: in other words, instead of finding the actual complexity of the program (which is not possible as you've said), the system checks if the running time exceeds a given time (for random inputs in the range). possible?